# Propagate auto updates to multiple joomla sites

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, auto-update

**This is the idea:** I have multiple sites done in Joomla 2.5.9, then I looking for a way to automatically update all sites at one time. So, I will test in my dev machine if the update runs well, then I give the permission to update all sites.

So the version `2.5.9` should be updated to `2.5.11`. Currently I am doing the update manually, but for 20 websites or something is really annoying.

Does anyone know any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newest solution on the block is [AdminCredible](http://admincredible.com) which is built to do exactly what you're asking.

We tried it when it launched but it wasn't up to our requirements at that time, and now we don't have 200+ websites to look after so it's no longer of interest, but, I've heard good things of recent versions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the playback function of [Selenium IDE](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/ide/) for that. Just replace 'test' with 'macro', when reading the description.